# Loop django template

Tags: django, loops

What I want to have: iterate each user that post data, and if the username of the post is equal to the one that is connected then write "foo".

Problem: I think that o.user doesn't give me information between the {% %} or if statement.
         The funny part is that o.user does give me information outside the ifequal ( in the p tag)

I don't find the mistake I did ...

```
<div class="secondblock"  >

           {% for o in p %}


               {% ifequal user.username o.user %} Foo
               {% endifequal%}
                    <p style="box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgb(216, 216, 216); background-color:white; padding : 10px;margin-top:5px;text-align:left; max-height:75px; overflow:auto; border: 1px solid rgb(229, 229, 229); "><span style="color: red;font-weight: 400; cursor:pointer;">{{o.user|upper }}</span> <span style="font-size:0.9em; float:right;">{{o.createdat}}</span>
                    </br>
                    </br> {{o.postit}} </p>


            {% endfor %} 


        </div>
```

formmodel:

```
class StoryForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Topic

        exclude =('user','createdat','comment')
```

model :

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    postit = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    createdat = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    '''createdat = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updatedat = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    def created(self):
        return self.createdat

    ''' 

    def updated(self):
        return self.updatedat  

    def timer(self):
        return self.createdat


    def username(self):
        return self.user

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.postit
```

my view:

```
def chat(request):
    '''
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect('/login/?next=%s' % request.path)

    return render(request,'chat/chat.html')
    '''


    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = StoryForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            storyi = form.save(commit=False)
            storyi.user = request.user
            storyi.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/chat/')

    else:
        form=StoryForm()

    try:
        p = Topic.objects.all().order_by('-createdat')[:5]
        #p.encode('ascii', 'ignore')

    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        p= "don't try it again"

    return render(request,'chat/chat.html',{'form': form, 'p':p})
```

Comment: Can't you print `user.username` and `o.user` before `ifequal`? By the way, don't write "lol", better write "foo" or "bar".

Comment: you are comparing a string with a user object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now you are comparing an object user with username, try like this:

```
{% ifequal user.username o.user.username %}
...
```

Comment: In my model  user is the username so i don't think this changes anything

Comment: @nokker From you model you try compare user object and string(username). It's not correct. Try to use my code.